# hex to int number format exception in java

Tags: java

I am getting a number format exception when trying to do it

```
int temp = Integer.parseInt("C050005C",16);
```

if I reduce one of the digits in the hex number it converts but not otherwise. why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would cause an integer overflow, as integers are always signed in Java. From the [documentation of that method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (emphasis mine):

> An exception of type `NumberFormatException` is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - **The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.**

It *would* fit into an *un*signed integer, though. As of Java 8 there's [Integer.parseUnsignedInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-) (thanks, [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas)):

```
int temp = Integer.parseIntUnsigned("C050005C",16);
```

On earlier Java versions your best bet here might to use a `long` and then just put the lower 4 bytes of that `long` into an `int`:

```
long x = Long.parseLong("C050005C", 16);
int y = (int) (x & 0xffffffff);
```

Maybe you can even drop the bitwise "and" here, but I can't test right now. But that could shorten it to

```
int y = (int) Long.parseLong("C050005C", 16);
```

Comment: *"But that's no option in Java"* Not true any more, since Java 8: [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-). You will of course have to print the value unsigned too, using [`Integer.toUnsignedString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-).

Answer (score 5):

C050005C is 3226468444 decimal, which is more than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). It won't fit in `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

`long temp = Long.parseLong("C050005C",16);`

Answer (score 2):

The signed int type ranges from 0x7FFFFFFF to -0x80000000.