# hex string to decimal conversion

Tags: java

I need to convert the string of hex to decimal in java..

My hex value is **"00000156A56BE980".**

My required output is **1471654128000**

I have done the following in java,

```
public static void main (String args [])
{
  String hexValue = " 00000156A56BE980 ";
  Integer result = Integer.parseInt(hexValue, 16);
 System.out.println(result);
}
```

but I am getting the following error,

> Number format Exception for input string "00000156A56BE980"

I have tried by giving long also the same error coming.. For other hex value it's coming but when we give hex string of larger value it shows the error.

How can we convert this number to decimal?
Can anyone solve this issue for me?

Comment: Yeah I have tried tat also.. The same error throwing..

Comment: You get a `NumberFormatException` because there's a space at the end of the string you're trying to parse. Get rid of the space. Also, if the value is too large to fit into an `int` you'll get this exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like so

```
import java.math.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        String hexValue = "00000156A56BE980";
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(hexValue, 16);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

See also this [repl.it](https://repl.it/CpUY)

The problem is probably because your value does not fit within the value range (-2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>32</sup>-1) of `Integer` - see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: `repl.it` is still not working

Comment: new BigInteger(hexValue) is working for me.. Thanks Dax. .

Comment: @Taurus: Nice to hear.

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I tried it from several systems now - the link is not dead; I guess you have an issue on your end ...

Comment: i think i have I'm getting error `This site can’t provide a secure connection` lol

Answer (score 1):

The number is too large for a 32-bit `int`

Try using a `long` instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hexValue = "00000156A56BE980";
    long result = Long.parseLong(hexValue, 16);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Note: you can't have spaces in a number.  You can call `.trim()` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

2 thing in order the code can work:

1. remove spaces trimming the String
2. the result doenst fit in an integer so use either Long or BigInteger instead

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hexValue = " 00000156A56BE980 ";
    long result = Long.parseLong(hexValue.trim(), 16);
    System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is too big for integer (> 2^32).

(The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.)

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599205/hex-to-int-number-format-exception-in-java)