# How to Convert Hex "F08282AC" to char

Tags: java

I am trying to convert hex string "F08282AC" to char using below code

```
Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)
```

but it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "F08282AC"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
```

How can I convert it to char?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599205/hex-to-int-number-format-exception-in-java

Comment: What character(s) are you expecting as a result?

Answer (score -1):

1) Characters can only hold 16 bits.

The number you have would far exceed that. If you meant a character array, you could use the `String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(hex, 16)).toCharArray()`

In parts, we convert the number to base 10, then convert it to a string, then convert it to a character array of numbers.

Comment: The title says “to char” and the question mentions “to char” twice.

Comment: Ah you're right. I will edit my answer.

Comment: *"Characters can only hold 8 bits"* A `char` is a 16-bit unsigned integer value, so that's wrong. This is Java, not Python.

Comment: sorry, my apologies. @Andreas. This isn't a great question in the first place, because it doesn't make a lot of sense.